# UWP intercept unhandled exception

Tags: c#, windows-10-universal

I have Class/ViewModel with INotifyPropertyChanged
[image]

Class/ViewModel binded on page and PropertyChanged called many times
[image]

But some times last call stop app
With no exception or details

[image]

Some time code is work good
[image]

**Problem1:** How intercept Exception (try-catch present in code)?

**Problem2:** How find differences?